# csquotes - Error when trying to define portuguese variant

Tags: csquotes

I'm trying to use `csquotes` and to define the variant `brazilian` for the portuguese language.

Following the package documentation, I've called the package with:

```
\usepackage[autostyle,portuguese=brazilian]{csquotes}
```

However, when trying to compile, latex issues an error, namely: "Package keyval Error: portuguese undefined. \ProcessOptions*" (in line 2465 of `csquotes.sty`).

I've played with other languages and variants, and they work fine. Only when attempting to set it for portuguese language (in either variant) I get the error.

A MWE of the issue is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,portuguese=brazilian]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\enquote{Something.}

\end{document}
```

It is true that I can "cheat" and manually redefine the quote style for the portuguese variant with the values of the brazilian variant, as defined in `csquotes.def`. That can be done by adding to the preamble (I suppose after `csquotes` has been called):

```
\DeclareQuoteStyle[portuguese]{portuguese}
{\textquotedblleft}
{\textquotedblright}
[0.05em]
{\textquoteleft}
{\textquoteright}
```

And with this, I wouldn't need to set the variant in the package options, thus getting rid of the error.

But I suppose this not the best way to deal with the issue.
Any clues or suggestions on why this might be happening or what should I do with it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `csquotes.def` part of the package is missing a line:

```
\DeclareQuoteOption{portuguese}
```

This should be reported as a bug, as far as I can tell.  For the moment your workaround is the simplest fix, I think. I have reported the bug to the current maintainer, and a fix has been submitted to CTAN. If you are using a current TeXLive or MikTeX, wait a few days and update your packages to get the fixed version.

Comment: I guess you are correct, @alan. And, kudos! for I got not only the answer but the package bug report plus the fix. Thanks a lot! And please thank Joseph Wright as well. It may be sometime before I enjoy it, for I'm using the TeXLive from the Ubuntu repositories. But it's perfectly fine. I can live with the workaround for the moment.